# How can I "mark as spam" in Sparrow for iOS?

Tags: spam, email

I have labels, archive, trash, respond, etc. but can't find any way to tag a message as spam on the iPhone version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the messages list, swipe left on the message to mark as spam, tap on the label icon, and select Spam.

Comment: funny - I don't think of it as a label, so I didn't look there.   Perfect.

Comment: Yes, it is not as obvious at it probably should be.